# How can I set value at a column in Jtable through javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jtable

```
updateAction: function(postData) {
                console.log("updating from custom function...");
                return $.Deferred(function($dfd) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'HallManagementServlet?action=UpdateStudent',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: postData,
                        success: function(data) {
                            var last_payment_date = [];
                            $.each(data, function(entryindex, entry) {
                              last_payment_date.push(entry['payment_expires_on']);
                            });
                           var current_date = new Date();
                           if(Date.parse(last_payment_date)<Date.parse(current_date)){
                              paymentStatus = 'Due'; 
                           }
                           else{
                               paymentStatus = 'Paid';
                           }
                            $dfd.resolve(data);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $dfd.reject();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Here paymentStatus is that column. It has two options.
More precisely this is the column

```
paymentStatus: {
                title: 'Payment Status',
                width: '8%',
                options: {'Paid': 'Paid', 'Due': 'Due'},
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: true
            },
```

I want to set the values from updateAction. How can I do that?